# Struts2 token interceptor redirection

Tags: struts2, token

I am using sturts2 token interceptor to stop multiple submission but problem is that when  fire two requests. 
I only get response of second request which is invalid token error how can i get response of first request which is success page. 
for eg. if i fire second request i should get error msg than i want to redirect to success page according to first request.

Comment: use TokenSessionStoreInterceptor which can provide much better logic for when invalid tokens are found.

Comment: Be careful using the `TokenSessionStoreInterceptor` in clustered environments, though.  In cases of cluster replication, the token is lost, and the interceptor will return the `invalid.token` result.  Just something to be aware of!

Comment: but i have to show response of first request  TokenSessionStoreInterceptor not wokring for this